# Describe a twisted parabolic trough

Tags: surfaces, parametric

I want to describe a parabolic trough of the form $z=x^2$ and give it a twist, like a torsion in $y$ direction. Does anybody know how I can do that?

[image]

Imagine this is the trough and the $z$ direction would be my $y$ direction. Thats the best image I could find to make it clear. It doesn't matter what direction the twist is in, really as long as it looks like that.

Comment: What are you mean by "a torsion in $y$ direction"? Is the direction $y$ twisted?

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: @uitty400: Are you looking for a surface whose "horizontal" cross-sections are parabolas, and these parabolas "rotate as the height of the section changes"? (If so, how exactly do the sections change, e.g., what is the center of rotation, is the rotation uniform, ...?) And are you looking for a parametric description, an implicit description, or something else?

Comment: @user86416: Yes your way of describing it fits what I'm looking for. Center of rotation could be the focal point of each parabola. In a first step I'm just looking for any description, whatever way it's the most easiest.

Comment: one could also think of a red bull can of which you grab at the upper and lower end and twist them the opposite way. But yes, I'm really looking for the parabolic trough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parabola has equation $y = x^{2} - a$, and is rotated about the origin at angular speed $k$ as the "horizontal" section moves along the $z$-axis, the resulting surface may be given the parametric description
\begin{align*}
x(u, v) &= u\cos(kv) - (u^{2} - a)\sin(kv), \\
y(u, v) &= u\sin(kv) + (u^{2} - a)\cos(kv), \\
z(u, v) &= v.
\end{align*}
The plot below shows $a = 1$ and $k = \pi/4$, for $-1 \leq u, v \leq 1$.

(This gives a couple of parameters to play around with, and should suggest how to rotate at non-uniform speed, or have the shape of the section change with height, or....)

[image: Surface swept by a rotating parabola]

Comment: Thanks! How did you get those equations? Didn't find anything similar whereever I looked.

Comment: @uitty400: You're very welcome. :) The expression $$(x', y') = (x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta, x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta)$$gives the coordinates of "$(x, y)$ rotated about the origin by $\theta$". The equations come from taking $$(x, y) = (u, u^{2} - a),\quad \theta = kv,$$namely, parametrizing a parabola with $u\mapsto(u, u^{2} - a)$, and letting the parameter $v$ control both the "height" $z$ of a planar slice and the angle through which the parabola is rotated. Naturally, there are variations on the idea; particularly, the coordinate functions can be permuted if needed, as in heropup's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the parabola is to be rotated about its focus, then we must have parabolic sections of the form $$z = ax^2 - \frac{1}{4a}, \quad a \ne 0.$$  Without loss of generality we may suppose $a > 0$, and suppose that for each unit increase in $y$, the parabola is rotated by some angle $\theta$.  This yields the parametrization $$\begin{align*} x(u,v) &= u \cos (\theta v) + \left( au^2 - \frac{1}{4a} \right) \sin (\theta v) \\ y(u,v) &= v \\ z(u,v) &= \left( au^2 - \frac{1}{4a}\right) \sin (\theta v) - u \sin (\theta v). \end{align*}$$

The below animation corresponds to varying $\theta \in [0,2]$ for a fixed $a = 0.5$:

[image]

The below animation corresponds to varying $a \in [0.05, 2]$ for a fixed $\theta = 1$:
[image]

For some reason, now I have a craving for pasta.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very good answer! I accepted the other one as correct though just because he was first to respond and also gave me what I needed.