# Gradient of a parametric form

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric

I want to find the gradient of a parametric form. So say you have the form

$$(x,y,z) = (f(u,v),g(u,v),h(u,v))$$ and now I want to find and the gradient in parametric form. How do I do that?
The background is that I want to plot certain geometric objects given in parametric form but then I also want to plot the gradient field which I need in a parametric description aswell.

Comment: Is your goal to plot a unit normal field on the image of your parametrization? If so, that's straightforward (and doesn't require gradients). :)

Comment: Well no not quite. If I have a parabolic trough for example ;) I want to plot its gradient field in form of a plane. So in explicit notation: $y=x^2 \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=2x$. Imagine that in 3D and $2x$ would be a 3D plane through the origin with slope 2. I hope I explained that good enough.

Comment: Your surface example is what I'd guessed. :) So, you want to find/plot tangent planes to your surfaces (and/or planes through the origin parallel to tangent planes)?

Comment: Well I want to plot surfaces that exist of exactly the same set of points in the ($x$,$y$)-plane that my originals do. These second surfaces should represent the gradient of each point of the original surfaces in their own z component. I guess thats how it has to be. Im not sure if you call that tangent plane.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\vec}{\mathbf{x}}$Not sure I understand exactly, but here are some observations that may help. The two vector-valued partial derivatives
$$
\vec_{u} = \left(\frac{\dd f}{\dd u}, \frac{\dd g}{\dd u}, \frac{\dd h}{\dd u}\right),\quad
\vec_{v} = \left(\frac{\dd f}{\dd v}, \frac{\dd g}{\dd v}, \frac{\dd h}{\dd v}\right)
$$
are tangent to the surface, along the curves $v = \text{const.}$ and $u = \text{const.}$, respectively. Their cross product $\vec_{u} \times \vec_{v}$ is orthogonal to the surface.

For your "[twisted-parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097519/describe-a-twisted-parabolic-trough)" surfaces,
$$
(x, y, z) = \bigl(u\cos(kv)−(u^{2}−a)\sin(kv), u\sin(kv)+(u^{2}−a)\cos(kv), v\bigr),
$$
this cross product is everywhere non-zero. In fact, $\vec_{u}$ is "horizontal" at each point (i.e., parallel to the $(x, y)$-plane), and so is tangent to the parabola that sweep out the surface, while $\vec_{v}$ is nowhere horizontal.

From your first comment, perhaps you want the plane through the origin spanned by $\vec_{u}$ and $\mathbf{e}_{3} = (0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would the parametric version of this span would look like?

Comment: Cause I know that a plane would look like this $\boldsymbol{P}=\boldsymbol{O}+t\cdot\boldsymbol{x_u}+s\cdot\boldsymbol{e_3}$ but then I had four variables and I only can have two.

Comment: @uitty400: Your parametric equation for a plane is fine; the variables are $s$ and $t$. :) (Or are you counting the surface parameters $(u_{0}, v_{0})$ as well? Those are fixed to describe a tangent plane at one point. This issue is related to my uncertainty about what exactly you want to plot.)